# How to customize tag input type datetime-local in the html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to customize the calendar, that is, when we click on the input and the calendar opens, I can change the font type, language of the calendar to Farsi and change the style, how can I access these items?

```html
<input type="datetime-local">
```